# What is the optimal way of merge few lines or few words in the large file using NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, large-files, nodejs-stream

I would appreciate insight from anyone who can suggest the best or better solution in editing large files anyway ranges from 1MB to 200MB using nodejs.

Our process needs to merge lines to an existing file in the filesystem, we get the changed data in the following format which needs to be merged to filesystem file at the position defined in the changed details.

```
[{"range":{"startLineNumber":3,"startColumn":3,"endLineNumber":3,"endColumn":3},"rangeLength":0,"text":"\n","rangeOffset":4,"forceMoveMarkers":false},{"range":{"startLineNumber":4,"startColumn":1,"endLineNumber":4,"endColumn":1},"rangeLength":0,"text":"\n","rangeOffset":5,"forceMoveMarkers":false},{"range":{"startLineNumber":5,"startColumn":1,"endLineNumber":5,"endColumn":1},"rangeLength":0,"text":"\n","rangeOffset":6,"forceMoveMarkers":false},{"range":{"startLineNumber":6,"startColumn":1,"endLineNumber":6,"endColumn":1},"rangeLength":0,"text":"f","rangeOffset":7,"forceMoveMarkers":false},{"range":{"startLineNumber":6,"startColumn":2,"endLineNumber":6,"endColumn":2},"rangeLength":0,"text":"a","rangeOffset":8,"forceMoveMarkers":false},{"range":{"startLineNumber":6,"startColumn":3,"endLineNumber":6,"endColumn":3},"rangeLength":0,"text":"s","rangeOffset":9,"forceMoveMarkers":false},{"range":{"startLineNumber":6,"startColumn":4,"endLineNumber":6,"endColumn":4},"rangeLength":0,"text":"d","rangeOffset":10,"forceMoveMarkers":false},{"range":{"startLineNumber":6,"startColumn":5,"endLineNumber":6,"endColumn":5},"rangeLength":0,"text":"f","rangeOffset":11,"forceMoveMarkers":false},{"range":{"startLineNumber":6,"startColumn":6,"endLineNumber":6,"endColumn":6},"rangeLength":0,"text":"a","rangeOffset":12,"forceMoveMarkers":false},{"range":{"startLineNumber":6,"startColumn":7,"endLineNumber":6,"endColumn":7},"rangeLength":0,"text":"s","rangeOffset":13,"forceMoveMarkers":false},{"range":{"startLineNumber":6,"startColumn":8,"endLineNumber":6,"endColumn":8},"rangeLength":0,"text":"f","rangeOffset":14,"forceMoveMarkers":false},{"range":{"startLineNumber":6,"startColumn":9,"endLineNumber":6,"endColumn":9},"rangeLength":0,"text":"s","rangeOffset":15,"forceMoveMarkers":false},{"range":{"startLineNumber":6,"startColumn":10,"endLineNumber":6,"endColumn":10},"rangeLength":0,"text":"a","rangeOffset":16,"forceMoveMarkers":false},{"range":{"startLineNumber":6,"startColumn":11,"endLineNumber":6,"endColumn":11},"rangeLength":0,"text":"f","rangeOffset":17,"forceMoveMarkers":false},{"range":{"startLineNumber":6,"startColumn":12,"endLineNumber":6,"endColumn":12},"rangeLength":0,"text":"s","rangeOffset":18,"forceMoveMarkers":false}]
```

If we just open the full file and merge those details would work but it would break if we getting too many of those changed details very frequently that can cause out of memory issues as the file been opened many times which is also a very inefficient way.

There is a similar question aimed specifically at c# [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33390596/what-is-the-best-way-to-merge-large-files). If we open the file in stream mode, is there similar example in nodejs?

Comment: Inserting data into a file at certain line numbers is a hugely inefficient operation.  If the file is stored as a single file in the file system, there is no way to avoid reading the entire file.  You have to read the file line by line counting lines up to the point of insertion, read the data you are about to overwrite and then rewrite the rest of the 
file at a new location past the new data. As the file gets large, if it can be stored in chunks where you keep a catalog of how many lines are in each chunk, then it's possible to insert a line into a chunk by only reading that entire chunk.

Comment: So, basically editing a large file by lines is hugely inefficient and there's no way around that inefficiency without going to a different way of storing the data that makes it easier to insert data without rewriting large amounts of data.

Comment: Yes, I agree, I'm looking for ways to open the file in chunks and edit only the chunk the editing range required and save it instead of whole file. But I doubt that type of thing exists yet.

Comment: In an OS file, you can't "insert" data into the file with node.js.  There is no interface for that.  You can edit any specific set of bytes by just specifying the desired file position for `fs.write()`.  But, that replaces bytes in the file, it doesn't insert.  As I said above, there are not file features for inserting data into the middle of a file.  You have to overwrite everything from the insertion position to the end of the file, first writing your new data and then rewriting the prior file contents after the data you inserted.

Comment: As I've already said, if you want a more efficient way of inserting data, you have to invent a better way to store the data that allows for more efficient insertions.  Storing in one large file will not be efficient to insert data.

Comment: This is more like an editor tool, a user opens a file from the browser and does anything or everything like IDE.

Comment: If some other language uses an optimal way then I think it would be better to find that option as you saying nodejs might not have that option.

Comment: Then you need an in memory structure for referencing the data.  A text editor is a very old programming problem.  Numerous architectural options which you can likely research.  Too bad that isn't what your original question asked about.  The programming language you use is pretty irrelevant.

Comment: Or go find a pre built editing widget of which there are zillions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would appreciate insight from anyone who can suggest the best or better solution in editing large files anyway ranges from 1MB to 200MB using nodejs.
>
> Our process needs to merge lines to an existing file in the filesystem, we get the changed data in the following format which needs to be merged to filesystem file at the position defined in the changed details.

General OS file systems do not directly support the concept of inserting info into a file.  So, if you have a flat file and you want to insert data into it starting at a particular line number, you have to do the following steps:

1. Open the file and start reading from the beginning.
2. As you read data from the  file, count lines until you reach the desired linenumber.
3. Then, if you're inserting new data, you need to read some more and buffer into memory the amount of data you intend to insert.
4. Then do a write to the file at the position of insertion of the data to insert.
5. Now using another buffer the size of the data you inserted, take turns reading another buffer, then writing out the previous buffer.
6. Continue until the end of the file is reach and all data is written back to the file (after the newly inserted data).
7. This has the effect of rewriting all the data after the insertion point back to the file so it will now correctly be in its new location in the file.

As you can tell, this is not efficient at all for large files as you have to read the entire file a buffer at a time and you have to write the insertion and everything after the insertion point.

In node.js, you can use features in the `fs` module to carry out all these steps, but you have to write the logic to connect them all together as there is no built-in feature to insert new data into a file while pushing the existing data after it.

> There is a similar question aimed specifically at c# here. If we open the file in stream mode, is there similar example in nodejs?

The C# example you reference appears to just be appending new data onto the end of the file.   That's trivial to do in pretty much any file system library.  In node.js, you can do that with `fs.appendFile()` or you can open any file handle in append mode and then write to it.

---

To insert data into a file more efficiently, you would need to use a more efficient storage system than a single flat file for all the data.  For example, if you stored the file in pieces in approximately 100 line blocks, then to insert data you'd only have to rewrite a portion of one block of data and then perhaps have some cleanup process that rebalances the block boundaries if a block gets way too big or too small.

For efficient line management, you would need to maintain an accurate index of how many lines each file piece contains and obviously what order the pieces should be in.  This would allow you to insert data at a somewhat fixed cost no matter how big the entire file was as the most you would need to do is to rewrite one or two blocks of data, even if the entire content was hundreds of GB in size.

Note, you would essentially be building a new file system on top of the OS file system in order to give yourself more efficient inserts or deletions within the overall data.  Obviously, the chunks of data could also be stored in a database too and managed there.

---

Note, if this project is really an editor, text editing a line-based structure is a very well studied problem and you could also study the architectures used in previous projects for further ideas.  It's a bit beyond the scope of a typical answer here to study the pros and cons of various architectures.  If your system is also a client/server editor where the change instructions are being sent from a client to a server, that also affects some of the desired tradeoffs in the design since you may desire differing tradeoffs in terms of the number of transactions or the amount of data to be sent between client and server.

> If some other language uses an optimal way then I think it would be better to find that option as you saying nodejs might not have that option.

This doesn't really have anything to do with the language you choose.  This is about how modern and typical operating systems store data in files.

Answer (score 0):

In `fs` module there is a function named `appendFile`. It would let you append data in your file. [Link](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_path_data_options_callback).

Comment: How we can edit the file based on a specific position instead of appending to the end of the file?